# Unique new users per period

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

In psql, I've written a query that returns unique users per week with

```
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)
```

However, I am also interested in counting the number of unique new users per week, in other words, users that have never been active before in any of the previous weeks.

How would one write this query in postgresql?

Current query:

```
SELECT  TO_CHAR(date_trunc('week', start_time::date), 'YYYY-MM-DD') 
AS weekly, COUNT(*) AS total_transactions, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS unique_users 
FROM transactions 
GROUP BY  weekly ORDER BY  weekly
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `min` to get the first appearance of a user_id. Use that to calculate unique users per week. You may also want to include grouping on year.

```
select 
TO_CHAR(date_trunc('week', first_appearance), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS weekly, 
COUNT(*) AS total_transactions,
COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS unique_users
from (SELECT t.*,
      MIN(start_time::date) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id) AS first_appearance
      FROM transactions t
     ) t
GROUP BY weekly
```